# Let's nuke [publish] and [publishing]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

### The situation

The [publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/publish) (1,436 questions) and [publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/publishing) (770 questions) tags are used across a very wide range of topics, including questions about

- [publishing Android apps on Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28125278),
- [publishing iOS apps on the App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28131623),
- [publishing research on RPubs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28060506),
- [publishing .NET applications on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28078803),
- [registering DLLs in .NET applications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27981197),
- [the `publish()` function in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27991128),
- [putting SQL source into TFS version control](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27941156),
- [automatically moving built files to a public server with Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27965633),
- [BizTalk web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28196193),
- [troubleshooting HTTP errors in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27944151), and
- [publishing JARs to a local Maven repository](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27752776).

That's just from the current front pages of both tags.

### The proposal

I believe that these tags are largely useless and should be considered for removal.

If removal is not possible, let's at least consider merging them. The choice between which to use appears to be arbitrary, and there is considerable similarity between the two tag wikis:

- From [the `publish` wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/publish/info):

  > To publish is the process to make something publicly available. This might be the stuff that happens inside a CRM system after editing an article and finally publishing it, or publishing a project artifact.
- From [the `publishing` wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/publishing/info):

  > releasing software to users. This may include releasing compiled binaries on a hardware medium, for download, or permitting access to a non-development web service.

#### Prefixed tags

Some folks have suggested adding prefixed versions of these tags for a few use cases. I'm entirely on board with that. Here is a short list of suggested prefixed tags:

- `meteor-publish`, for questions relating to [Meteor's `publish()` function](http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Meteor-publish)
- `oneclick-publish`, for questions relating to [Microsoft's One-Click Publish feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I agree that [publish] and [publishing] are not useful, but we should consider prefixed variants before burninating.  I'm not familiar with [meteor] but the results for [meteor][publish] suggest a [meteor-publish] tag might be viable, for example.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, works for me. I suspect that 80-90% of the existing questions tagged with [publish] and / or [publishing] can simply have the tag removed, but it does make sense to add a more specific tag in some cases.

Answer (score 12):

I do not think these tags should be burninated. While it is true publish(ing) software is not always done from a code standpoint, it can be and several popular frameworks do allow for it, or for its setup in xml or code.

The few question shown in your post merely show the wide variance of the tag, but I am not sold that that requires it to be entirely removed as it does add context. There is a one click publish in asp.net mvc that requires setup in xml for example.

One of the comments shows that there is a meteor api function publish. Any time there is an actual api related to a vague word it is best to prefix it (as suggested) and make it relate to the api.

This just goes to show that these tags need to be cleaned, or reviewed. But I do not think burnination makes as much sense here, and I certainly didn't see 90% misuse of the tag.

Comment: Exactly my thought. I remember having a lot of problems when I tried to publish my first Desktop app with Visual Studio 2010. Making the tags specific to the framework being used would make a lot of sense.

Comment: I do like the idea of prefixing a few useful versions of `publish`, but I still struggle to see the value of the plain `publish` and `publishing` tags.

Comment: So, what would be the point of having the `publish` and `publishing` tags after replacing them with *meaningful* tags everywhere?

Comment: @SamB - I don't think they all must be replaced, only the ones which are specific to an api or process. `publish` still makes sense in wide variety of posts, just like `form` does even though it is used in many different contexts.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like we should:

1. **Replace these tags with meaningful tags:**

   - [meteor-publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor-publish) for [meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meteor)'s `publish`
   - *[add tags here as you find/make them]*
2. Either **patrol the unprefixed tag(s) forever** (in which case the wiki should link here) or **salt them** (which would ideally also link here)

Comment: What does it mean to salt a tag?

Comment: Chris: to prevent the tag name from being used again, like "burninate", except that salting would imply that you've already gotten rid of tag usage, whereas "burninate" implies that questions might get slightly singed.

Answer (score 1):

I usually agree with the Jeffrey/SamB's approach for these tags, but unfortunately a lot of publishing processes don't have a specific technology name nor are clearly married with a particular technology.

For example publishing an ASP.NET/MVC site could be tagged [visualstudio-publish] because it is exposed as a feature of Visual Studio, but could also be considered part of the core .NET framework [.net-publish] or ASP.NET [asp.net-publish]

I don't think it makes sense to create a specific tag such as [sometechnology-publish] if there isn't a specific publishing tool/technology that is a core part of sometechnology.

In many technology stacks there is no defacto tool or process for publishing.  Therefore the [publish] tag deals more with the conceptual best practices of deployment. In which case I think it serves a purpose in providing context for the question.

Comment: I'm not clear what your stance is on the existing [publish] and [publishing] tags. Do you support their removal, or do you see value to them?

Comment: @Chris It is not a great tag, but I think it is moderately useful.  I strongly  think trying to replace it with more technology specific tags is **not** useful in this case.  I would let it be for the most part, perhaps redirecting publish to publishing.

Comment: At minimum, I think making one a synonym of the other is a good idea. I have just added a suggestion to make [publishing] a synonym of [publish].

Comment: Well, what does [tag:publishing] refer to: Publishing web sites? Releasing software? What book publishers do? What print-on-demand shops do?

Comment: @Chris: that sounds backwards to me, honestly.

Comment: @AaronLS: Also, when I said patrolling, I didn't mean to imply anything as simple as that the tags would necessarily end up empty; just that it seems like it would be best to replace them with more specific ones where applicable.