# Are questions about publishing on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Publishing is a very vast topic as it is associated to [many technologies](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284786/lets-nuke-publish-and-publishing). We also have the [publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/publish) [publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/publishing) tags.

IMHO questions about publishing are:

> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.

but I am not sure because of how the community reacts to such questions. Few examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28624839/android-app-publishing-error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125278/updating-app-in-google-store-without-key-store-path-file

[xcode ERROR ITMS-90093= this bundle is invalid. apps that include arm64 architecture cannot have minimum OS Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131623/xcode-error-itms-90093-this-bundle-is-invalid-apps-that-include-arm64-architec)

I hope I am making sense.

---

To be more specific I am more concerned about the questions regarding [google-play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-play) as I am mostly active for [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android).

Comment: "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development." I highly doubt it.

Comment: to be more specific I think this because deploying the product to the corresponding store/platform or making it live is also part of software development

Comment: @SMR licensing is also "part of software development", but at its core a legal issue and thus off topic for SO. I think questions could theoretically be on-topic but most will be support requests that are better directed to the company (e.g. the user who lost his key can maybe get help from google support, but definitely not from SO) or otherwise off topic. As always, judge by the specific question, not by the tags or broder topics.

Comment: @l4mpi fair enough.. different questions have different context. As i stated that this may fall in various categories but what should be done in case of issues which can only be handled by the developers only.

Comment: Note that [tag:appstore-approval] specifically mentions that such questions aren't on-topic

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can both agree that the particular question you tagged me in was badly written enough it should have been closed anyway.  As for why I think they should be off topic in general-  I think it opens the door to a whole lot of questions that we don't want.  Do we want dozens of questions on "Why did Apple reject my app?" (answer:  even they don't know half the time, consistency is not their strong point).  Would we accept a question about "How do I let people download my app from a website?" (roughly the same thing).  I wouldn't blanket say any question about an app store is off topic, but I would want to see a technical issue in it and not a policy issue.

As for publish and publishing tags-  when you say publishing, I think of data warehousing and providing access to data, the idea of publishing an app doesn't come close.

Comment: Yes exactly all the questions can not be accepted about publishing. SO is obviously not a customer support. I think we can agree that it totally depends on **how close is the question relevant in terms of programming.**   If someone is having issues due to any **configuration or code** with can be handled by the **developers only/by programming** then I think it makes an on-topic question. Right? Ultimately the community is always there to decide.